# Application Compilation using Graphics Card

Tags: visual-studio, compilation

During the Microsoft Windows 10 Devices event, Panos Panay - whilst talking about the Surface Books graphics said the following:

> It's for that coder, using the latest Visual Studio where they can compile using the GPU and CPU at the same time and not lose a minute ([Video](https://youtu.be/W7wN8DAPh80?t=4981))

This could just be a throwaway comment, but given that it is possible to do CPU type activities on the GPU (CUDA?), I wondered if he was actually talking about a genuine way to make Visual Studio use both the CPU *and* the GPU to perform application compilation.

Looking online, I can't see an obvious answer. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If they use something like [AMP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh265137.aspx) underneath then that is exactly what it is designed to do... use CPU and GPU (heterogeneous computing).